# What's the fastest way to find if a string is not in a group of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

I have a bunch of strings and I need to be able to tell if I have already used them.  Right now I add all of the strings to a main string called titles.  I then used:

```
#titles = some string with a bunch of strings in it
#n_title is the the string I want to check if it is in titles
if n_title not in titles:
   #do something
else:
   #do something else
```

My question is would it be better if titles was a dictionary or an array or are they all the same run time?  I believe most of the time my `n_title` will not be in the titles, if that makes any difference.

Comment: A `set()` is likely fastest.  Definitely faster than a `list`.  O(1) vs. O(n).

Comment: @Mark: If `titles` is a string with a bunch of strings in it, using a `set` isn't going to help.

Comment: @martineau Obviously, put the "bunch of strings" in a set, not a single string.  The OP did say "if titles was a dictionary or an array [would it be the same runtime]".

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? There's ambiguity here.

Comment: @Mark: Then it depends entirely on how expensive putting all the substrings into a `set`  is — which isn't obvious from what's in the question (or to a noob).

Comment: better test differen methods and use module `time` to see which is the fastest in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

use set() instead of list() because sets is much faster than lists.
lists have duplicates values in it but sets does not contain any duplicates so lesser data becomes faster to find.

titles = {'tilte1', 'tilte', 'tilte3'}
n_title = 'title4'
if n_title not in titles:
#do something
else:
#do something else

Comment: There is no list involved here.

Comment: "lists have duplicates values in it but sets does not contain any duplicates so lesser data becomes faster to find." That is also not why `set` objects are faster, btw

Comment: Uraiz: For future reference: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @martineau thanks sharing the formatting help i will be careful next time.